# How to change the tab browser name for each documents using the metadata?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, managed-metadata, browsers

In my company we use our own metadata to create name codes for document management purposes. However that codes are the Doc Name that are presented in the tab browser. When a lot of documents are open in different tabs people are confused with the tabs names. Is there any way to change the tab names to show the Doc Title instead of the Doc Name? (Other of the metadata fields)

[image: example]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint Modern

Comment: As in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I'm new at this

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way of changing this from SharePoint, since it's actually Excel Online that you're viewing in that tab.

If you would like Microsoft to change the title of the browser tab or provide configuration options for Excel Online, you can provide feedback via the [Microsoft Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/c23f3b77-f01b-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: Thank you Callum.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If the answer was helpful, please do remember to upvote or mark the answer as accepted to help inform the community.